# Axis part coloring

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I try/want to color the x-axes in a special way. I want to get the bottom x-axis red, but not the whole line. Only the 3 parts under the graph have to be colored. I tried it with options

```
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={-stealth,red},
```

but both x-axes completely get red. Is there a possibility to get what I want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,backgrounds,fit,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel style={align=right},xlabel=Output (MW),
ylabel=Input (\$/h),unbounded coords=jump, xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},  xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,extra x ticks={0,2,4,6,8,9},extra x tick labels={,$P_{pz}^-$,$P_{pz}^+$,,,}]
\addplot+[black,smooth,no markers] coordinates {
(0,0) (1,1) (2,4) (3,inf)
(4,16) (5,25) (6,36) (7,inf) (8,64) (9,81)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\draw[red!70!black,ultra thick] 
  ({axis cs:0,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:2,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0});
\draw[red!70!black,ultra thick] 
  ({axis cs:4,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:6,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0});
\draw[red!70!black,ultra thick] 
  ({axis cs:8,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:9,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0});` but I'm sure there's a more economical way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option using the `axis description` and `axis` coordinate systems (but I have the feeling that there's a simpler way):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,backgrounds,fit,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel style={align=right},
  xlabel=Output (MW),
  ylabel=Input (\$/h),
  unbounded coords=jump, 
  xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},  
  xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
  ytick=\empty,
  xtick=\empty,
  clip=false,
  extra x ticks={0,2,4,6,8,9},
  extra x tick labels={,$P_{pz}^-$,$P_{pz}^+$,,,}
]
\addplot+[black,smooth,no markers] coordinates {
(0,0) (1,1) (2,4) (3,inf)
(4,16) (5,25) (6,36) (7,inf) (8,64) (9,81)
};

\draw[red!70!black,ultra thick] 
  ({axis cs:0,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:2,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0});
\draw[red!70!black,ultra thick] 
  ({axis cs:4,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:6,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0});
\draw[red!70!black,ultra thick] 
  ({axis cs:8,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0}) -- ({axis cs:9,0}|-{axis description cs:0,0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]